# 'google-chrome' and 'chrome'

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

On SuperUser I'm trying to clean up google tags, and I noticed that there are 266 tagged 'google-chrome' and 58 just 'chrome'.

Could some please do a batch retag of [`chrome`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=chrome) to [`google-chrome`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=google-chrome)?

**Edit:**  Since Tim has explained to me the different meaning of chrome, I'll go through all these by hand, so that nothing is tagged inappropriately.

**Edit2:**  OK, all done, there was one that needed to stay labeled chrome.

Comment: but are all those tagged `chrome` about Google Chrome or about the portions of the interface referred to as chrome?

Comment: What about those who are asking a question about inhaling toxic materials to get a cheap high? http://au.reachout.com/find/articles/chroming - they miss out :(

Comment: @Farseeker: they should be tagged [not-programming-related]

Comment: +1 thanks Lance for going thru them manually.

Comment: @George: No, there are several questions on meta about not using that tag (e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag); just close the question instead.  However, this question is about SU, not SO. :)

Comment: @Roger, even closed questions should be retagged appropriately.

Comment: @Lance: And the majority of meta seems to say that [not-programming-related] is not an appropriate tag. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27666/questions-with-tag-not-programming-related-is-closed-by-marking-it-as-not-pro/27667#27667

Comment: @Lance: btw, i found one question tagged **[googe-chrome]** (sic) earlier today.  yes, it was you.  just watch those typos, ok?  :)

Answer (score 10):

`Chrome` when discussing browsers is not at all exclusive to Google. Unfortunately, you were down voted twice without explanation.

[Browser Chrome](http://www.answers.com/topic/browser-chrome) refers to the design and functionality of the browser itself, as it presents itself to the user.

[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) is a brand that suggests a better browsing experience by its namesake.

While I use Google Chrome as my browser, I can only suggest that 'better, faster, etc' remain entirely subjective. The word (hence tag) 'chrome' was around prior to Google releasing a web browser.

You gotta keep em separated :)

Answer (score 2):

I've just looked this over again; after Lance's retagging, there were only two questions left in the **[chrome]** tag.  One was about the [*browser-chrome* concept](https://superuser.com/questions/97500/is-there-a-quick-way-to-remove-browser-decorations); one was about the [*Windows* UI](https://superuser.com/questions/38687/windows-program-to-remove-titlebar-frame-etc-from-a-window).

There were also six *new* questions tagged **[chrome]** which all needed the **[google-chrome]** tag instead.

I've retagged the first two with **[ui]** instead of the confusing **[chrome]**, and merged the others into **[google-chrome]**.  The tag autocomplete should suggest **[google-chrome]** to those who type "chrome" in manually.

Unfortunately this probably won't be the last we'll see of **[chrome]**.